# Anchor href attribute on Master.cs being overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, anchor

We have a Master page (asp.net) with a menu item (html anchor) which should not be populated with a href for a certain user role - but it's always showing!

The Master.cs has:

```
<li><a id="manage" runat="server" href="~/Views/Manage.aspx" title="Manage details">Manage </a></li>
```

In the **OnLoad** event on the Master.cs we remove the HRef attribute if it's a certain user type - that seems to work OK, I've checked in the Watch window.

```
manage.Attributes.Remove(Constants.HREF_ATTRIBUTE);
```

The Watch windows confirms the HRef attribute being blanked out but as soon as the Master.cs is displayed the HRef is back again, as if the HRef in the aspx has overwritten the 'removal' in the code.

Bear in mind this is my first post - I've tried to google it, to no avail. Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Works fine for me with a simple ASPX page. You sure you don't have other code that add the `href` back in?

Comment: Changed the link in Master.cs to have 'DEBUG' in the link and that showed up in the HRef attribute, so Master.cs is the thing that is undoing the blanking out. But the code in the OnLoad event should be handling it.

Answer (score 3):

Since your anchor is a server side control you should use its [`Href`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.href.aspx) property instead of removing an attribute:

```
manage.Href = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - it's a weird fix! Can I just say, I'm bug fixing this system, I didn't write it!

A image was missing from the solution, so an error was occurring then being gobbled - causing a redirect to the error page which had the master.css applied to it.

Very strange and not one I'd expect anyone to get.
Thanks for looking,
Pete